# How can I encrypt SHA512 hash with salt in C and ubuntu?

Tags: c, hash, sha512

I'm trying to encrypt hash with salt.

In command line, I found right hash written in the shadow file using below command.

openssl passwd -6 -salt abcd appple
$6$abcd$vIWAp1OzuGuo376cRkZ5DXcgI8KIlnUibsk.iydtfCFqb9okOz.S70Ysu7.qRRg9Me5XwAyTjkZBQJXiIxwpL/

And I tried to get it in C using openssl([How to convert a raw 64-byte binary to Hex or ASCII in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702475/how-to-convert-a-raw-64-byte-binary-to-hex-or-ascii-in-c)).

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
        char data[] = "abcdapple";
        unsigned char hash[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH*2+1];
        SHA512((unsigned char *)&data, strlen(data), (unsigned char *)&hash);

        char buffer[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH*2+1];
        for(int i =0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i)
                sprintf(&buffer[i*2],"%02x", (unsigned int)hash[i]);
        printf("digest: %s\n", buffer);
        printf("\n");
}
```

but generated hash is ea1d5a8b11297d20f954a3ab15092d21b733484b2eb9b7226b2b138639f0df30627774945458a774eb279cd83d2e977a2bc5599606d6a9a3b2f075f9b1895ecd, which is different from right thing.

I think I didn't use salt well. Also there seems to be a fundamental problem.
Can't I implement encrypt program with salt using C?

Comment: You don't "encrypt" hashes, with or without salts, to begin with...

Comment: @AKX your mean is it just create a hash?

Comment: No you cannot just concatenate. Notice the beginning of the hash. `$6$abcd$`. The 6 corresponds to `-6` in your command, and after that you have the salt in clear text.

Comment: @klutt If I can calculate hash using salt, Can't I just concatenate $6$abcd$ before created hash?

Comment: @Guk Don't know. I just told you why your approach does not work. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to generate is not an ordinary SHA-512 hash.  It's a *hashed password* using a special-purpose algorithm *based on* SHA-512.  `openssl passwd` computes this algorithm, but the OpenSSL library's `SHA512` function computes ordinary SHA-512.  This special-purpose algorithm, and several others with the same function, are documented in the [crypt(5) manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man5/crypt.5.html).

You can *probably* use the [`crypt_r`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man3/crypt.3.html) function, from the [`libcrypt`](https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt) library (this library is inaccurately named for historical reasons; it *only* provides password-hashing algorithms), to compute hashed passwords using the same special-purpose algorithm as `openssl passwd` does.  On my computer, this program prints the same string starting with `$6$abcd` that you got:

```c
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct crypt_data cd;
    memset(&cd, 0, sizeof cd);
    puts(crypt_r("appple", "$6$abcd", &cd));
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how the second argument (referred to as a "setting string" in the documentation I've been linking to) contains both the salt value `abcd` and the prefix `$6$` (which tells `crypt_r` to use the SHA-512-based hash).  It works this way so that `login(1)` can call `crypt_r` with the password it just read from the tty as the first argument, and the password entry from the shadow file as the second argument, and if it gets back the same string it put as the second argument then the user has successfully authenticated.

Compile and run like so:

```
$ gcc -std=gnu11 -O test.c -lcrypt
$ test $(./a.out) = '$6$abcd$vIWAp1OzuGuo376cRkZ5DXcgI8KIlnUibsk.iydtfCFqb9okOz.S70Ysu7.qRRg9Me5XwAyTjkZBQJXiIxwpL/'; echo $?
0
```

I say *probably* because the set of special-purpose hashing algorithms supported by this library varies from Unix to Unix.  If (and only if) you can put the string `$6$abcd$...` in some account's password entry in `/etc/shadow` and then successfully log in as that account using the password `appple`, then it should work.

libcrypt may also have a function called [`crypt_gensalt_rn`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man3/crypt_gensalt.3.html) which you can use to generate setting strings and select an appropriate hashing algorithm.  Here's a demo of that function:

```c
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char setting[CRYPT_GENSALT_OUTPUT_SIZE];
    crypt_gensalt_rn(0, 0, 0, 0, setting, CRYPT_GENSALT_OUTPUT_SIZE);

    struct crypt_data cd;
    memset(&cd, 0, sizeof cd);
    puts(crypt_r("appple", setting, &cd));
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile and run *this* program it will *not* print the string starting with `$6$abcd`; it will print something else, such as

```
$y$j9T$0aVoGQ/PFN0PHbcYlKZdZ1$05NbMJLbRliM7fmtSAeZoy3OoRsBqETpAZXQpnPey82
```

and what it prints will change every time you run it, but each of the strings it outputs will be usable as an `/etc/shadow` entry allowing someone to log in with password `appple`.  You can control its behavior with the first four arguments that I left at 0.

(Disclosure: I am one of the authors of lib(x)crypt.)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I think I understand the content of the article to some extent. The codes was successfully worked! (I edited crypt_r("appple", "$6$abcd") into crypt_r("appple", "$6$abcd", &cd) because of gcc error).
It helps me a lot!!

Comment: Oops, yes, that was my mistake.

Comment: I have to define `_GNU_SOURCE` for this to compile successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source for the `openssl passwd` command (and in particular the core `do_passwd` function) over at GitHub: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/8ea761bf40e6578ecd95ec47772ef86a2e4d4607/apps/passwd.c#L795-L874

The (very non-trivial, 290-line) SHA-512 passwd hash computation function is found a little above that, at https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/8ea761bf40e6578ecd95ec47772ef86a2e4d4607/apps/passwd.c#L509-L793

You're probably better off just calling `openssl passwd` from your app as a subprocess.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see it.